# CakePHP Completely Random 403 AJAX Errors

Tags: ajax, cakephp, backbone.js

I using CakePHP with Backbone.JS, I set up a controller just to give me a JSON output for getting my data, e.g. client names etc, to pass into each Backbone model.

This was all working, or appeared to be, however, it seems that it now gives me some random 403 errors when the page / from is saved or reloaded. But I have no idea why? If it can access it to start with, and does, then why would it not have access after a save or reload?

I have tried, `$this->Auth->allow` and it dose appear to fix the problem but this data is or could be important and need it not to be access my everybody who might guest at my access path.

Now I have read a number of articles on her, most point to read/write access on the files your accessing, but in my case its just a path  `/XXXX/XXXXX/myjson/clients` For example.

Now I can post my code, if needed, but I am not sure what the problem is, is this a CakePHP issue or is Backbone not requesting the data right?

Please be aware that I am dyslexic, please be kind about my question, if I have not explained myself right. Then please be me some time to re-word / edit my post.

Thanks,

Comment: Update: I am still at a lost as to what I can do to solve this? [PLEASE HELP.....] - I am now working on the fact it might be a problem with CakePHP 2.6.1, so I build a whole new copy of Cake, also taking the time to update it to 2.6.2. But not sure why its an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any one else looking at this, I had added `autoRegenerate` to the Configure Write Session. For some reason it looks like CakePHP was taking to long to regenerate a new cookie and request my information at the same time.